# Make HTML Form Responsive

Tags: html, css, forms, responsive, bootstrap-5

I am unable to make this HTML Form responsive. It looks fine on desktops but not on mobiles and tablets.
Here is the link to the code:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geekycoder/L0y514oh/)

I have tried removing body's `overflow: hidden` and `white-space: nowrap;` and using different types of col but it does not work. I think my `stack` class and `padding` in some places is causing the problem but I am unable to fix it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're making forms just with HTML. Maybe try to use bootstrap form https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/ . It will be easier to make forms responsive.

Comment: try to use some sort of container

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 5.2 and I also tried to put the main div inside a container but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

CSS media queries are the basis of responsive web design. Try something like:

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  div {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello World
</div>
```